# Issue Generating jHipster with dev PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, spring-boot, jhipster

First off, I love the framework... it is a lot of fun. I'm still getting to know my way around and don't have any issues when generating the project with a hsqldb dev database, but I am unable to get it generate when trying to connect to a local PostgreSQL db at localhost. Is there something I am missing?

Error output:

```
[?] (3/7) Do you want to use Hibernate 2nd level cache? Yes, with ehcache (local cache, for a single node)
[?] (4/7) Do you want to use clustered HTTP sessions? No
[?] (5/7) Which *production* database would you like to use? PostgreSQL
[?] (6/7) Which *development* database would you like to use? PostgreSQL
[?] (7/7) Would you like to use the Compass CSS Authoring Framework? No

undefined:33
((__t = ( localhost )) == null ? '' : __t);
          ^
ReferenceError: localhost is not defined
    at eval (eval at template (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-    jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:6305:22),     <anonymous>:33:11)
at JhipsterGenerator.underscore [as _engine] (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-    jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/util/engines.js:32:30)
at JhipsterGenerator.engine (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/actions/actions.js:303:10)
at JhipsterGenerator.template (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/actions/actions.js:281:15)
at JhipsterGenerator.app (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/app/index.js:169:10)
at /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:341:43
at /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:551:21
at /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:227:13
at iterate (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:134:13)
at /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:145:25
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not your fault, it's a bug :-)

I have referenced it here: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/105

And I did a bugfix release just for you: http://jhipster.github.io/2014/01/23/jhipster-release-0.8.1.html

Comment: Wow. That was an amazing response time... Makes me want to devote myself and my company to this framework even more.. I do have one question though... and this may be just be my postgres config... It builds fine now (even off npm) but now when I run mvn spring-boot:run, I'm getting a connection pool error:

[ERROR] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariPool - Maximum connection creation retries exceeded

Comment: This looks like your application can't reach the database. HikariCP is our connection pool, it is configured in the application-*.yml files

Comment: FYI: I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit, npm 1.3.23, node 0.10.15, java 1.8.0 (could be an issue, but not likely), and I've tried to increase postgres concurrent connections, but it's already at 100. My background comes from Java and Hibernate and I've had issues with Hibernate grabbing a ton of connections, but I don't think that is the issue here...

[ERROR] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariPool - Maximum connection creation retries exceeded
[ERROR] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariPool - Timeout of 5000ms encountered waiting for connection.

Comment: Maybe you can update the HikariCP version? From 1.2.6 to 1.2.8

Comment: Nope. It's not you. I somehow managed to bone by postgres install during this little debug experiment. You are awesome and I thank you for you're crazy fast help!